# Variable sliding window in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am using Excel 2010, but I presume this would be solved the same in any version of Excel.

I have data that I would like to sum - essentially providing a sliding cumulative value. For example, on a table with a 1000 rows, I'd like a column showing the sum of the current row's value and the preceding X rows, where X is a number I'd like to specify in another cell. For example, the last 6 rows cumulative value or the last 5 or 8 or whatever.

I tried various combinations using ADDRESS and INDIRECT, INDEX, etc. - but nothing seemed to work.

Here's an example, showing the desired results, where the window size is 2:

```
  |A     |B
1 |Value |Cumulative
2 | 1    |   
3 | 2    |3
4 |15    |17
5 |10    |25
6 |11    |21
7 | 8    |19
```

and for window size 3

```
  |A     |B
1 |Value |Cumulative
2 | 1    |   
3 | 2    |
4 |15    |18
5 |10    |27
6 |11    |36
7 | 8    |29
```

As I said, I'd like the size of the window to be specified in another cell in the spreadsheet (e.g., named "WindowSize").

If the window size is such that it would go beyond the valid data, it would be nice if it returned a blank or 0 value - but that's not essential. I don't mind ignoring #Refs or manually adjusting the beginning of the column to account for that.

I'd like to believe this can be done with a formula and without having to resort to visual basic. Can it?

Thanks,
Yosh

Comment: Apologies to the answerers for my delayed acknowledgment. I got hit with an emergency diversion & only got back to this today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Index method:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)<$E$1,"",SUM(INDEX(A:A,(ROW()-$E$1)+1):INDEX(A:A,ROW())))
```

INDEX is a non volatile function, in that it only recalculates when the data to which it referes changes.

Both [OFFSET() and INDIRECT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx) are volatile functions. Volatile Function calculates every time excel recalculates. So if there are a lot of them it slows down the calculations with unneeded calcs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Scott. Your answer has a couple clear edges over the others. 1) it includes the IF to handle the top of the cumulative column - automatically clears or fills rows according to the Cumulative value - nice. 2) As the table fills, it will indeed have thousands of these calculations, so your comment about volatility made me choose yours as the right answer. Adjustments I made: =IF(ROW()<Cum+1,"",SUM(INDEX(A:A,(ROW()-Cum)+1):INDEX(A:A,ROW()))) --"Cum" is a named cell with number of cumulative values (instead of $x$y). "+1" handles the header row.

Comment: P.S. I'm not sure why you used 1:1 in the ROW function - using ROW() checks if the current row is far enough down for the comparison.

Comment: I used the ROW(1:1) because my data started on row 2.  If i had use ROW() the counter would have started with 2 instead of one and if the value in E1 would have been 2 then the window would have tried to Sum that first number with the title.  By using Row(1:1) it does not matter in which row the numbers start it will always start at 1 and not the row it is in.  If your data starts in row 1 then using ROW() is best, if not the first numbers will be in error. It basically removes the need for the +1.   @yoshm

Answer (score 1):

This should work on cell `B2`:

```
=SUM(A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A2)-($D$2-1),1,4)))
```

The window value is in cell `$D$2`.

Comment: Thanks - your answer taught me more about how to use INDIRECT so I gave an upvote. However, I didn't check it thoroughly so I can't vouch that it's working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the offset function

```
=sum(offset(A2,0,0,D1))
```

where D1 has the number of rows in it.

Comment: OK, this one is almost right. However, the D1 should be an absolute reference, $D$1. I like this one's simplicity, too. However, @Scott's comment about volatility made me take a closer look at his answer after I worked with this one. Upvote for the nice simple answer. Thanks.